# We are getting a slew of requests from IE9 for /scanImageUrl

Tags: internet-explorer-9

The requests are all from Internet Explorer 9 with compatibility mode turned on. We know compatibility mode is on, because of the trident attribute being sent in the user-agent string.

This just started recently.(3/28 around 6AM)

These are legitimate users, not bots, we have determined that and we cannot reproduce the issue.

Here is one new Google search result, and it appears that [others](http://www.webmasterworld.com/webmaster/4560505.htm#msg4560681) are having the same issue.

Comment: Do you use [this logo](http://images.scanalert.com/meter/www.travelguard.com/31.gif) from McAfee by chance? What's the URL of your website?

Comment: no, we do not use that logo. I wonder though if it's some 3rd party  plugin for IE9, and perhaps a mcaffee plug in.

Comment: helps if you link the URL in question.

Comment: If you try googling 'scanImageUrl' is comes up with many URLs ending in that string...

Comment: We are getting plenty of /scanimageurl requests on our website especially for IE 8 and IE 9, anybody has any ideas of why its happening.

Comment: this started on 3/28/2013 6:15AM and is still going today...

Answer (score 4):

One of my coworkers started exhibit the symptoms (random requests for http://www.vistaprint.com/scanImageUrl from IE8), so I hopped on her computer to figure out what was causing the issue.

The problem appears to be due to a malware IE add-on called Yontoo v2.051.  I doubt anyone intentionally installs the software, but, among other installers, it is bundled with "EZ Fonts" (http://downloadfreely.com/start/?p=EZ-Fonts).  Disabling both parts of the add-on from IE stops the issue.

On a fresh install on EC2, the problem seemed to instead stem from "Surf Canyon" v5.0.1.  Disabling Yontoo v2.052 didn't fix the problem, but disabling Surf Canyon did.  In addition to the requests for scanImageUrl, Surf Canyon even causes random redirects to completely malformed URLs.

Comment: FYI, we also started to see the problem around 5:50AM EDT on 3/28.

Comment: Yes, that's the exact same time we have started encountering this issue.

Comment: Received the same problem. Grmbl, thought it was an error...